# CSS align elements starting from center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to align elements in a bootstrap col starting from the center all the way to top and bottom. example:

- When there is one element:

  ```
      <div class="col-md-3">


       <span> item #1 </span>


       </div>
  ```

Element one is centered on the middle with empty margins above and below.
When pushing more items:

- When there are two elements

  ```
       <div class="col-md-3">


        <span> item #1 </span>
        <span> item #2 </span>


       </div>
  ```
- When there are three elements

  ```
       <div class="col-md-3">

        <span> item #1 </span>
        <span> item #2 </span>
        <span> item #3 </span>

       </div>
  ```
- When there are four elements

  ```
        <div class="col-md-3">

        <span> item #1 </span>
        <span> item #2 </span>
        <span> item #3 </span>
        <span> item #4 </span>

       </div>
  ```

Not so accurate but something like this - Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/23ktww1o/1/

Comment: so use `text-center` class of bootstrap

Comment: @Amitsingh, I think EnderCode is looking for the vertical alignment. :)

Comment: question is not clear make fiddle or give a image showing what do you want ?

Comment: yes vertical alignment sort of

Comment: @Amitsingh, if it isn't clear, then why do I and Abhitalks understand it ;) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `span` I use a list in my example:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.col-md-3 {
    min-height: 100px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.col-md-3 ul {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 2.2;
    font-size:16px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.col-md-3 ul li {
    display: block;
    background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- One item -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Two items -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Multiple items -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for, but its not working in my case. Is it because I removed the min-height  that u added in the col-md-3. 
I remove it becuase I want the list to always take the height of the parent the col

Comment: heres the css:

div.stain {

    padding-top: 8px;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.patient-sharing ul{
display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style: none;
    background: lightgreen;

}

div.stain li{

display: block;
}

Comment: What happens when you change the `min-height` to `100%`?

Comment: was removing line-height issue and not the height.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your `span`s `display: block`;
2. Wrap your `span`s in a `div` with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`

**Example**:

```css
div.col-xs-3 { height: 240px; display: table}
div.cell  { 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
}
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"> 
      <div class="cell">
         <span> item #1 </span>
         <span> item #2 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9"> 
         <span> item #1 </span>
         <span> item #2 </span>
         <span> item #2 </span>
         <span> item #2 </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Edit: (based on op's comment)

In order to make the `div` take up the height of the parent, make it `100%` and also `display: table` to the parent. You can also have the height on the `row` `div` and set `100%` on the inner `col`.

Comment: this would work. I need the cell div to take the height of the bootstrap col the parent, and when I only have one span it is not centered.

Comment: @EnderCode: Updated the code in the answer. Give the height as `100%` and it will take the height of its parent (you will also need to give the parent a `display: table` for that to take effect). One span is also vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to align it vertically use on the class

```
 <div class="col-md-3" style="vertical-align:middle">


  <span> item #1 </span>
  <span> item #2 </span>


 </div>
```

else you can use text-center on the div

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of flexible box solution. Just need to add the below CSS code. *Code explained in comments*

**CSS**

```
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Vertically stacking */
  justify-content: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  align-items: center; /* Needed only if you want to limit the width */
  height: 300px;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

*Code modified for SO snippet presentation.*

**Output:**

```js
// jQuery added for testing the vertical alignment

var i = 0;
var newItem = "<div class=\"item\">item</div>";

$('.hide-item').click(function() {
  $('.container-flex').find(':first-child').remove();
});

$('.add-item').click(function() {
  $('.container-flex').append(newItem);
});
```

```css
.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.item {
  background: #3f51b5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-3 container-flex">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<br>
<button class="btn hide-item center-block">Hide item</button>
<br>
<button class="btn add-item center-block">Add item</button>
```

Comment: Need not to change the col-md-3 height. Not working in my case, although that's exactly what i need.

Comment: Create a demo of your code with my solution. I will find the bug and adjust your code.